# One JMS message copied to two queues

Tags: queue, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

How do I configure activemq such that a JMS message published to a topic is passed on to two JMS queue.
Is this possible in activemq?

Or

Is it better to use a simple topic with two subscribers. Both picking up their own copy of a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to configure the Broker to do this you are better off using [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/) to create the routing behaviour you are looking for.  [Camel routes](http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html) can be embedded in you ActiveMQ instance.

Comment: I will look into this, but just a quick clarification. Is Apache Camel an ESB (like WESB, WMB, Tibo Business Works etc...)?

Comment: Using Apache Camel now.